# List view border of each row in android

Tags: android, listview, border

Am doing a design as following screen shot but am not able to get exactly as showing in the screen shot.

[image]

Here my list view

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="@drawable/redemption_request_list_border"
    android:dividerHeight="5px"
    />
```

These are all the item am displaying in the list view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lblRedemptionDate"
                    android:text="Redemption Date"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lblTrackingId"
                    android:text="Tracking ID"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Loyalty ID :"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:id="@+id/lblLoyaltyId"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblRedemptionDate"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
                    android:text="Loyalty ID"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblTrackingId"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Status :"
                    android:id="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblLoyaltyId"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                    />
                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="190dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    style="@style/spinner_style"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_button_font_size"
                    android:id="@+id/spnRdmStatus"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgStatusEdit"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:id="@+id/txtRdmStatus"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgStatusEdit"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_charge_card_edit_view"
                    android:id="@+id/imgStatusEdit"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_status_success"
                    android:id="@+id/imgStatusSave"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btnViewItems"
                    android:text="View Items"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here my border of list view but border not showing.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFF" />

    <stroke android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

and am getting this design

[image]

Any one can help this, Thanks!

Comment: use cardview with recyclerview insted of listview you will get exact layout as you want

Comment: but in card view is i can populate arraylist values like list view

Comment: you have to use recyclerview instead of listview and use cardview for each row use this link http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0):

Apply cardview in your item view layout like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblRedemptionDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Redemption Date"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTrackingId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Tracking ID"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLoyaltyId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblRedemptionDate"
        android:text="Loyalty ID :"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblTrackingId"
        android:text="Loyalty ID"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblLoyaltyId"
        android:text="Status :"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnRdmStatus"
        style="@style/spinner_style"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgStatusEdit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_button_font_size"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRdmStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgStatusEdit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStatusEdit"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_charge_card_edit_view" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStatusSave"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoyaltyId"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_status_success"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="View Items"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```